# Internal Server Error 414 - Request-URI Too Large

Tags: internal-server-error

I'm trying to delete around 250 posts at once, but the next page I am taken to displays the error:

> **Request-URI Too Large**
>
> **The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server**

Does Wordpress need to use a HTTP Post action to delete posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks.  I ended up deleting them through PHPMyAdmin.  They were all in the same category.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom page template and put this code in it. It will delete as many pages as you want.

```
<?php
global $post;

$args = array( 'numberposts' => 250 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :

wp_delete_post( $post->ID, true );

endforeach; ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts